# Set default browser used to open links from SeaMonkey

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-snow-leopard, seamonkey

I use the email client provided within Seamonkey.

However, I'd rather use Firefox to open links within email messages, however by default emails are opened in the Seamonkey browser. I would really like to remove the Seamonkey browser.

How can I set it to open URLs in Firefox?

Comment: What happens when you go to: "Edit -> Preferences -> Browser / Default Browser -> Set Default Browser"? Which one is set, and can you set Firefox?

Comment: I did some research and what you want just not seems to be possible. Here's a [poor guy with the same question](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.support.seamonkey/browse_thread/thread/8c79b9436be0b0c2/eeddadc814c0cafb?lnk=gst&q=open+firefox#eeddadc814c0cafb) that was posted more than one year ago. Seamonkey is just meant to be e-Mail and browser in one. If you want to stick to using mail from Mozilla, just consider migrating to Thunderbird.

Comment: Your original question was beyond broken as can be seen [here](http://superuser.com/posts/287961/revisions). Click the triangle next to revision 1. The question was wrong after @slhck's edits because it was already wrong before. All he did in the question body was fix your capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing an email application other than Mail

```
Open Mail (/Applications/Mail).
From the Mail menu, choose Preferences.
Click the General button.
Choose your desired default email application from the Default Email Reader pop-up menu.
```

Choosing a default Web browser other than Safari

```
Open Safari (/Applications).
From the Safari menu, choose Preferences.
Click the General button.
Choose a different browser from the Default Web Browser pop-up menu.
```

Comment: The OP has confirmed that setting the default browser on OS X will **not** result in Seamonkey opening them in it.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are not scared to spend some cash ($12) [Highbrow](http://www.heliumfoot.com/highbrow) might be a good alternative. You can determine via a shortcut which browser to use as a main browser and much more.
2. Another possibility - the obvious one - would be to grab the link via drag and drop and pull it to Firefox in your Dock/Sidebar/Toolbar/Desktor or where ever the small red animal has it's hideaway.
3. You could also use a Lauch Application like LaunchBar, Quicksilver or Alfred. Copy and paste the link then open the clipboard content in the preferred browser. This works for me with LaunchBar. You might have to google for some script or use Automator to create your own one to perform this action.

Comment: 1. I can open other urls (not in sea monkey) in firefox, my default browser. 2,3. Not really on click though. Thanks for your suggestions :(

Answer (score 1):

this add-ons is made for that:
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/seamonkey/addon/standalone-seamonkey-mail/
still continue to use Seamonkey Email client but switch to another (system) browser.
With the add-ons, links in email open in system browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be the only way to actually accomplish what OP is asking for... and not a moment too soon! ;)